Term for (and history) repeating main verb at the end of a sentence?
Consider the following:

I went to a wedding the other ooh there was a lot of it there, there was. (Bernard Cribbins)
I'm the best man for the job, I am (reddit post)
Huge heaps of old papers there are up there

The first two are clear examples of a common feature of (some, British?) English usage: repeating the main verb in a sentence, and some complementary word, at the end. It seems to me that it's a sort of intensifier. First question: is there a name for this?
The reddit thread linked above suggests that this is a construction mostly found in older variants, and/or in Welsh or Irish. Is there any data to support this?
Finally: does my third sentence above count as an example of the same kind -- it seems to me that the main verb only appears at the end of the sentence.
TIA.

We've had at least one question about this before--hard to search for it, though.

The (Northern) Irish usage is so it is. Yes, it is an intensifier. (NB The Bernard Cribbins quote should read the other day.)

The title is about repeating the main verb at the end of a sentence, but the question seems to be about repeating auxiliaries, which is why I say it's a duplicate.

It also appears in Old English.

The problem is that this is less a feature of English writing than of speech and song.  One example of the latter springs to mind:  the song "I'm [or "it's"] Henry the eighth I am I am, It's Henry the eighth, I am."   The problem is that this is less a feature of English writing than of speech and song.  One example of the latter springs to mind:  the song "I'm [or "it's"] Henry the eighth I am I am, It's Henry the eighth, I am."  Herman's Hermits "Henry The VIII, I Am" on The Ed Sullivan show can be found on the internet.
It may even be a speech habit of rural communities and one looked down in with fond condescension by the 'educated classes'.  So, if it appears at all in published writing, it will probably be in novels to reproduce the speech of rustics.  Thomas Hardy springs to mind but there will be others.  As for a label, the word for literary and especially oratorically repetition is anaphora, used to drive a point home.  The speech habit in the question is certain aimed at driving the point home, and so could be so called, even though it is stretching the intention of the term rhetoric to the limit.  It may even be a speech habit of rural communities and one looked down in with fond condescension by the 'educated classes'.  So, if it appears at all in published writing, it will probably be in novels to reproduce the speech of rustics.  Thomas Hardy springs to mind but there will be others.  As for a label, the word for literary and especially oratorically repetition is anaphora, used to drive a point home.  The speech habit in the question is certain aimed at driving the point home, and so could be so called, even though it is stretching the intention of the term rhetoric to the limit.
